# how to enable color for "Show App Icon"

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-dock

I switch the "Show Apps" icon to custom svg picture, but the color is grey, how can i change/enable colors for the svg icon? see screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `.svg` file itself and colourise it. You may use vector graphics editor like Inkscape to do so. You can install Inkscape from the Software store or open Terminal and run

```
sudo apt install inkscape
```

Alternatively you can install the snap version from the Software store or by running

```
snap install inkscape
```

Once installed open the `.svg` file with Inkscape and colour the part you want.